# List the packages imported by a given package precisely using R code?

Tags: r, cran

To see which packages are imported by any given package, we could visit the manual, and view under 'imports', or we could view the `DESCRIPTION` file if the repository is on github, but how can we do this using R code?

For example, if such a function were called `imports()`, and it were called on the [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) package, then `imports(rvest)` would return something like

```
[1] httr (>= 0.5), magrittr, selectr
```

Note: a less elegant way of seeing which packages a package imports could be to start a fresh R session, view the loaded packages, then load the package in question, and compare the lists (if there are many more loaded packages, those were imported by the package in question) - but I prefer not to use this method as it would require frequently starting a new R session.

Comment: Using `rvest` as an example there is an "Imports:" entry in the first table of its CRAN webpage: view-source:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the `packageDescription` function from the `utils` R package: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/packageDescription.html. it does exactly that, parse the `DESCRIPTION` file and returns a named list with the results.

Comment: @BenBolker:  Actually it works for uninstalled packages, provided they are expanded into a directory of their own.  Specify the parent dir as `lib.loc` and the function doesn't care that it's not really a library.

Answer (score 1):

For packages hosted on CRAN (or some specified R repository), this information is already handy in the matrix returned by `available.packages()`:

```
a1 <- available.packages()
a1["rvest","Imports"]
## [1] "httr (>= 0.5), magrittr, selectr"
```

Comment: This is also a very nice solution. I wonder if available.packages() accesses the web or if it’s resulting matrix ships with R?

Comment: `available.packages()` downloads the `PACKAGES.rds` file from the specified repository.